# Get ?-type Collider from child, and add duplicate component to parent

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-components

I'm trying to get a Collider of unknown type from a child object at run-time and add an identical Collider to the parent. How can I do that?
This is the best I've got so far, but doesn't work:

```
Collider MColl = GetComponentInChildren<Collider>();
gameObject.AddComponent<MColl.GetType>();
```

> "Error: 'MColl' is a variable but is used like a type"

Comment: What I sugest you do is create a mono behavior with fields that you can assign.  Then get that component and assign whatever you need.

Comment: @PhilippLenssen good catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it right. Use this to get it to work:

```
Collider collider = GetComponentInChildren<Collider>();
gameObject.AddComponent(collider.GetType()); // Assigns e.g. BoxCollider.
```

Good luck!

Comment: Works nicely now. Thanks.